# Lookup names where multiple IDs are in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with some data that looks like this, in a Customer table (there are other columns too):

| Customer ID | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 256,389 |
| 11112 | 789,564,468 |

There is also a Product table that contains a Product ID and Product Name (among other columns)

I need to write a query, which will form the basis of a view, that essentially substitutes the Product ID's for the Product names, but preserve it as a comma separated list in one column, so the output would look like this:

| Customer ID | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | Apples,Oranges |
| 11112 | Pears,Bananas,Melon |

I know this seems pretty horrible, and I have other tables that separate out each product onto each line using cross_apply, but the customer wants to see the data like this too.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: If you fix your design, you fix the problem. Use a normalised approach and this is a *literally* a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: The data comes in this format, and while I have used cross apply to separate the values for another use case, the customer actually wants to see it in the format I've asked for. I know its horrible design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared an example, I hope it satisfies your need

```
DECLARE @Tbl1 TABLE(ID INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl1 VALUES (1,100),(1,200),(1,300),(1,400)

SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Tbl1 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Value
FROM @Tbl1 t
GROUP BY ID
```